# Appending list using .capitalize() - compiler freezes with high RAM usage

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to swap str elements in list with same elements but capitalize their first letter.
While trying to achieve this I'm just step by stepping it and when I try to use for loop to just append list with capitalized elements, my compiler freezes and proceeds to gradually increase in RAM usage up to 90%.
I can guess it has to do something with built in functions that I use (probably incorrectly). Can anyone help me understand what is happening and how should I approach it?

Here is code:

```
title = 'a clash of KINGS'

out = title.split()

for i in out:
    out.append(i.capitalize())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change a list while iterating over it. You keep adding elements to `out` list. You can print `out` inside the loop and see for yourself. Even if it didn't enter into infinite loop, still you did not replace the initial values, but just add more and more elements.

you can use list comprehension

```
title = 'a clash of KINGS'
out = title.split()
out = [word.capitalize() for word in out]
```

you can combine last 2 lines into one

```
title = 'a clash of KINGS'
out = [word.capitalize() for word in title.split()]
```

Comment: Well that just solves it. So when I want to change elements in list I should use comprehension. What I did is a BIG no no.

Comment: you can iterate over your list in a loop and add the changed elements to different list.

Comment: For loop and add to other list, or comprehension when acting on the same list. Got ya! Thanks for clarification and help.

Comment: Solution provided by @GabrielPhelipe is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in a infinite loop. You're not accessing the  out element, you're keep appending a lot of elements inside the list. I think what you're trying to do is:

```
title = 'a clash of KINGS'

out = title.split()

for i in range(len(out)):
    out[i] = out[i].capitalize()
```

Comment: If I may suggest, if you want to get the index, use enumerate - `for i, item in enumerate(out):`, then `out[i] = item.capitalize()`